# Sympy won't simplify or expand exponential with decimals

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, polynomial-math

i'm trying to simplify a huge expression of powers of n , and one of the  results of sympy throws a (n+1)^1.0  , i noticed that

`f=n*((n+1)**1.0)
 sympy.expand(f)`

doesn't work  it stays the same instead of giving n^2+n, so i was wondering if there's any way to perform something like this

Comment: Can you clarify what Sympy throws?  An exception?

Comment: no it just returns f as exactly the same , but if i had 1 instead of 1.0 it actually expands the term

Answer (score 1):

Sympy will expand your expression as expected when the power is an integer number. If the power is stored as a rational or a float, it won't work. Your options are either to rewrite your expression using integers, or write some code that will automatically check if a float stores an integer number (up to numerical precision error) and act accordingly.

Here's a starting point for that:

```
def rewrite_polynomial(p):

    args_list = []

    if not p.is_Mul:
        return None
    for m in p.args:
        if not m.is_Pow:
            args_list.append(m)
        else:
            pow_val = m.args[1]
            if pow_val.is_Float:
                pow_val_int = int(pow_val)
                if pow_val.epsilon_eq(pow_val_int):
                    args_list.append(Pow(m.args[0],Integer(pow_val_int)))
                else:
                    args_list.append(m)
            else:
                args_list.append(m)                


    return Mul(*args_list)

n = Symbol('n')
f= n*((n+1)**1.0)
g = rewrite_polynomial(f)
print(g)
```

Comment: Do you know if they are working on fixing this issue?

Comment: I have no idea unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Based on Yakovs answer, I made a rewrite rule that makes a DFS traversal of the expression tree and replaces powers to integers in float type.

The code is probably not very efficient, but it worked for my use cases.

Since I'm not a sympy expert, I guess there are some edge cases where this code will break.

Anyways, here you go!

```
import sympy as s


def recurse_replace(expr,pred,func):
    if len(expr.args) == 0:
        return expr
    else: 
        new_args = tuple(recurse_replace(a,pred,func) for a in expr.args)
        if pred(expr):
            return func(expr,new_args)
        else: 
            return type(expr)(*new_args)

def rewrite(expr,new_args):
    new_args = list(new_args)
    pow_val = new_args[1]
    pow_val_int = int(new_args[1])
    if pow_val.epsilon_eq(pow_val_int):
        new_args[1] = s.Integer(pow_val_int)
    new_node = type(expr)(*new_args)
    return new_node

def isfloatpow(expr):
    out = expr.is_Pow and expr.args[1].is_Float
    return out

def clean_exponents(expr):
    return recurse_replace(expr,isfloatpow,rewrite)

x=s.symbols('x')
expr = (1+x) ** 1.0
s.pprint(expr)
expr2 = recurse_replace(expr,isfloatpow,rewrite)
s.pprint(expr2)
```

With output

```
       1.0
(x + 1)   
x + 1
```

Comment: In the end, I didn't need the code. After changing some other expressions to integers, the floating point exponents never showed up, and I never needed these simplifications.