# sympy not ignoring unimportant decimals in exponential expression

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

I have a code that calculate some mathematical equations and when I want to see the simplified results, it can not equate `2.0` with `2` inside power, which is logical since one is float and the other is integer. But decision was sympys where to put these two values, not mine.

Here is the expression in my results that sympy is not simplifying

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

y = -exp(2.0*x) + exp(2*x)
print(simplify(y)) # output is -exp(2.0*x) + exp(2*x)

y = -exp(2*x) + exp(2*x)
print(simplify(y)) # output is 0

y = -2.0*x + 2*x
print(simplify(y)) # output is 0

y = -x**2.0 + x**2
print(simplify(y)) # output is -x**2.0 + x**2
```

is there any way working around this problem? I am looking for a way to make sympy assume that everything other than symbols are floats, and preventing it to decide which one is float or integer.

this problem has been asked before by [Gerardo Suarez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243832/sympy-wont-simplify-or-expand-exponential-with-decimals) but not with a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another sympy function you can use called `nsimplify`. When I run your examples they all return zero:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x")

y = -exp(2.0 * x) + exp(2 * x)
print(nsimplify(y))  # output is 0

y = -exp(2 * x) + exp(2 * x)
print(nsimplify(y))  # output is 0

y = -2.0 * x + 2 * x
print(nsimplify(y))  # output is 0

y = -(x ** 2.0) + x ** 2
print(nsimplify(y))  # output is 0
```

**Update**
As @Shoaib Mirzaei mentioned you can also use the `rational` argument in the `simplify()` function like this:

```
simplify(y,rational=True)
```

Comment: I think the correct answer is adding `rational=True` inside `simplify`. this way everything turns out float, and problem solved. `simplify(y,rational=True)`

Comment: yeah that seems correct